# Frameset not showing up in FireFox or IE. Fine in Chrome..?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, frames, frameset

For some reason, this very basic page shows up fine in Chrome, but not FireFox or IE. I've never really needed to use Frames before, but they seem simple enough. Is there a problem with using a single frame within a frameset? I am trying to replace an iFrame with this single frame.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd"> 
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <frameset cols="*">
      <frame id="aqFrameSlider" src="http://www.alphacommunications.com/alphaquote/index.php?account=J2001&hash=GISDFGSP43HAJ49FH92JSPKJ">
    </frameset>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Is there a problem with using a single frame within a frameset?"   The problem is that you're using frames. Is there really no other work-around for whatever problem you have?

Comment: Well.. I am trying to come up with a way for my customers to embed a web site of mine in their own website. They pass some variables to the page as a "login" for their own pricing and such. Once logged in, the framed page hides its header/footer content to be easily embedded elsewhere. I would absolutely be open to other suggestions.. perhaps that is a question for another post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678511/how-to-embed-one-website-in-another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `<body>` and close `<frame>` properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd"> 
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <frameset cols="*">
      <frame id="aqFrameSlider" src="http://www.alphacommunications.com/alphaquote/index.php?account=J2001&hash=GISP43HAJ49FH92JSPKJ"></frame>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

The next time, you should [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your document first, that would notice this error.

Comment: Oh... <frameset> replaces <body>. Gotcha.